# I deleted all call log permissions and my app not showing on play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

Recently Google banned my app because I had CALL_LOG permissions, now I deleted everything related with this permissions and uploaded a new version, it let me do it but the app is not showing,

Answer (score 0):

It resulted I just had to upload the APK to the Play Store and wait around 24 hours for it to show again.